# LlamaIndex small-to-big chunking strategy in RAG pipeline, limits the chunk size a lot

Tags: metadata, large-language-model, chunking, llama-index, retrieval-augmented-generation

I am working on a RAG system using LlamaIndex. I try to adapt small-to-big chunking strategy for retrieval stage. I have numerous articles as inputs and some metadata about them. here is the list of metadata items:

- title
- date
- url
- keywords
- entities

```
model_id = "mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2"

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, load_in_4bit=True)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)

from llama_index.prompts.prompts import SimpleInputPrompt


system_prompt = "You are a Q&A assistant. Your goal is to answer questions as accurately as possible based on the instructions and context provided."


# This will wrap the default prompts that are internal to llama-index
query_wrapper_prompt = SimpleInputPrompt("<|USER|>{query_str}<|ASSISTANT|>")


import torch
from transformers import BitsAndBytesConfig

nf4_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
)

import torch
from llama_index.llms import HuggingFaceLLM


llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
    context_window=3900,
    max_new_tokens=1024,
    generate_kwargs={"temperature": 0.1,"do_sample": True},
    system_prompt=system_prompt,
    query_wrapper_prompt=query_wrapper_prompt,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    model=model,
    device_map="auto",
    model_kwargs={"quantization_config": nf4_config}
    #model_kwargs={"torch_dtype": torch.float16 , "load_in_8bit":True}
)

from llama_index.embeddings import LangchainEmbedding
from langchain.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

embed_model = LangchainEmbedding(
  HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="BAAI/bge-large-en-v1.5")
  )

from llama_index.node_parser import SimpleNodeParser

node_parser = SimpleNodeParser.from_defaults(chunk_size=1256)
base_nodes = node_parser.get_nodes_from_documents(docs)

# set node ids to be a constant
for idx, node in enumerate(base_nodes):
    node.id_ = f"node-{idx}"

# creates a persistant index to disk
client = QdrantClient(path="./qdrant_data")

# create our vector store with hybrid indexing enabled
# batch_size controls how many nodes are encoded with sparse vectors at once
vector_store = QdrantVectorStore(
    "qdrant", client=client, enable_hybrid=True, batch_size=10
)

storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=qdrant_vector_store)
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
                                                      chunk_size=1256,
                                                      chunk_overlap=0,
                                                      llm=llm,
                                                      embed_model=embed_model)

base_index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
    docs,
    storage_context=storage_context,
    service_context=service_context,
)

base_retriever = base_index.as_retriever(similarity_top_k=3)

from llama_index.schema import IndexNode

sub_chunk_sizes = [856, 920, 1024]
sub_node_parsers = [
    SimpleNodeParser.from_defaults(chunk_size=c, chunk_overlap=c // 2) for c in sub_chunk_sizes
]

all_nodes = []
for base_node in base_nodes:
    for n in sub_node_parsers:
        sub_nodes = n.get_nodes_from_documents([base_node])
        sub_inodes = [
            IndexNode.from_text_node(sn, base_node.node_id) for sn in sub_nodes
        ]
        all_nodes.extend(sub_inodes)

    # also add original node to node
    original_node = IndexNode.from_text_node(base_node, base_node.node_id)
    all_nodes.append(original_node)
```

when i try to use really small chunk sizes, due to my metadata, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Metadata length (1143) is longer than chunk size (856). Consider increasing the chunk size or decreasing the size of your metadata to avoid this.
```

i want to use the small-to-big chunking strategy to enhance the retrieval performance of the model but i do not know how to deal with this situtation. i keep increasing the sub-chunk sizes but it is getting away from the strategy.

I have also summaries of all the documents but, because of this reason, I had to remove them from my metadata.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When LlamaIndex embeds a document it includes the metadata, and when it sends a chunk to the LLM it also includes the metadata. The node parser knows that so it takes the length of the metadata into account. In this use-case you're using small-to-big so you don't need the metadata embedded or sent to the LLM, so you can exclude it from both of those using 2 properties of Nodes:
`excluded_llm_metadata_keys` and `excluded_embed_metadata_keys` ([docs](https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/api/llama_index.schema.BaseNode.html#basenode)).

In practice this looks like (modifying your code):

```
all_nodes = []
for base_node in base_nodes:
    for n in sub_node_parsers:
        sub_nodes = n.get_nodes_from_documents([base_node])
        sub_inodes = [
            IndexNode.from_text_node(sn, base_node.node_id) for sn in sub_nodes
        ]
        # Set excluded metadata fields for each sub_inode
        for sub_inode in sub_inodes:
            sub_inode.excluded_llm_metadata_keys = ["key1","key2"]
            sub_inode.excluded_embed_metadata_keys = ["key1","key2"]

        all_nodes.extend(sub_inodes)

    # also add original node to node
    original_node = IndexNode.from_text_node(base_node, base_node.node_id)
    all_nodes.append(original_node)
```